# Is there a way to put Binance API market buy orders in a way that decides the max buyable quantity itself and that I don't have to calculate it?

Tags: api, cryptocurrency, binance

I want my buy order to be executed instantly at the market price and the quantity should be the max buyable quantity, I shouldn't have to calculate it like *myBalance/coinPrice* sort of thing. I want to know if we can do that using binance API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special field `quoteOrderQty` for `MARKET` binance order types, where you can put quote currency amount.

Comment: can you please tell me if there's a similar way to conduct out limit sell orders, like sell 100 percent without typing in the quantity.

Comment: No way to limit orders. For limit orders, you need to put quantity. `Quantity = quote quantity/price`

Comment: Is this applicable for futures api ?

Comment: So in this case price and quantity will be null right?